# UPDATE QUERY :: ORA-01036 : Illegal variable name/number

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, oracle11g, updates

I am trying to execute an update query in Oracle 11g DB.

```
string query2 = "update map_pair_config set source_value=:PARA1,target_value=:PARA2,modify_user=:PARA3,modify_date=:PARA4 "
              + "where source_name=:PARA5 and target_name=:PARA6 and attribute_name=:PARA7 and source_value=:PARA8 and target_value =:PARA9";

OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand(query2, connection);

command2.Parameters.Add("PARA1", update_row.source_value);
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA2", update_row.target_value);
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA3", Environment.UserName);
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA4", DateTime.Now);
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA5", source_name.SelectedItem.ToString());
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA6", target_name.SelectedItem.ToString());
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA7", attribute_name.SelectedItem.ToString());
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA8", temp.source_value);
command2.Parameters.Add("PARA9", temp.target_value);
```

I have even checked the values passed in the parameters and they are correct. I have executed this query in toad and it works. But when I run it in my WPF application, I get an error.I even tried removing date parameter. But its still not working.

Help appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Missing `:`:

```
source_value=PARA8
             ^---
```

so you're trying to set `source_value` to be equal to the value of some unknown/undefined field `PARA8`.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. But I am still getting the same error. I tried running this code in Console Apllication and the db is updated. But its not working in WPF application.

Comment: Hey, it works! There was some error in the parameters value. Really sorry for the silly error though.